# SQL query to compare rows satisfying a time stamp condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp

I have a data in the following format.

```
Column1     Column2     Column3         TimeStamp
   10           20         30       2017-04-25 14:15:00.000
   12           30         40       2017-04-25 14:15:15.000
   55           54         89       2017-04-25 14:15:30.000
   66           78         11       2017-04-25 14:15:45.000
   12           30         40       2017-04-25 14:16:00.000
   55           54         89       2017-04-25 14:16:15.000
   66           78         11       2017-04-25 14:16:30.000
```

The time stamp  is in the format

> yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

The data is logged for every 15 seconds. Hence the difference between time stamps of any consecutive two rows should be 15 seconds. I'm interested in querying the rows whose time difference is let's say for example 20 seconds and 
between TimeStamps 2017-04-25 14:15:00 and 2017-04-25 14:15:30 respectively.

I started with the following code and its taking forever to finish querying.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  dbo.Temp2 AS t1
WHERE
  EXISTS
  (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      dbo.Temp2 AS t2
    WHERE
      t2.TimeStamp - t1.TimeStamp = 20      
  )
  ;
```

I'm using MS SQL Server 2017.

Any suggestions, ideas would be really helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: your sample data seems off... the timestamp is repeated (in blocks of 4) and thus, doesn't increment by 15 seconds... it steps back in time. What's the grouping?

Comment: I sincerely hope the timestamp values don't really use that format. That would mean they are stored as **strings**, which is a _big mistake_.  Much better if that column uses a **DateTime** type. DateTime columns use a _binary format_ that is not human readable, but is efficient for working with date values and is compatible with built-in date functions. It's possible you see the columns in the string format, but it's just the query tool trying to be helpful.

Comment: @scsimon My bad! It was a typo: Just updated it

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Time stamp is in 'datetime' format. So I think that won't be an issue.

Comment: No problem @Agni but there still isn't a gap > 15 seconds in the sample data. I did put this gap in my sample data below though. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lead/lag analytic functions might be helpful here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        DATEDIFF(s, TimeStamp, LEAD(TimeStamp, 1) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp)) AS diff
    FROM Temp2
    WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN '2017-04-25 14:15:00' AND '2017-04-25 14:30:00'
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE diff >= 20;
```

### Demo

In the above demo I had to doctor your sample data slightly to get anything to return, because your timestamp range actually has no values such that the next leading value is 20 seconds apart.

Comment: Sure. I get your point! In general, I would have thousands of time stamps logged in. However, I'll adjust this difference value according to my data sets.

Comment: I was just wondering how would I do the same in c# application using LINQ to SQL query.

Comment: @Agni You should probably open a new question in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Using `LEAD` and `LAG`. I also changed your sample data to actually have a gap longer than 15 seconds. This will return **both** rows for which the *gap* occurs. In this case, it's the two commented below.

```
create table #MyTable (C1 int, C2 int, C3 int, TimeStamps datetime)
insert into #MyTable
values
(10,20,30,'2017-04-25 14:15:00.000'),
(12,30,40,'2017-04-25 14:15:15.000'),
(55,54,89,'2017-04-25 14:15:30.000'),
(66,78,11,'2017-04-25 14:15:45.000'), --this row will also be returned
(12,30,40,'2017-04-25 14:16:15.000'), --changed minutes here. This is the only row > 15 second difference than the previous, ordered by TimeStamps
(55,54,89,'2017-04-25 14:16:30.000'),
(66,78,11,'2017-04-25 14:16:45.000')

;with cte as(
select
    *
    ,KeepMe = case when datediff(second,TimeStamps,lead(TimeStamps) over(order by TimeStamps)) > 20  or datediff(second,TimeStamps,lag(TimeStamps) over(order by TimeStamps)) < -20 then 1 else 0 end
from 
    #MyTable)

select
    C1
    ,C2
    ,C3
    ,TimeStamps
from cte
where KeepMe = 1

drop table #MyTable
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Since I can accept only one answer. I have upvoted your answer for the logic.